# How to get product information from product id in magento2 or magento2.0?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

How to get all product details by product id in magento2? I want to display a single product detail with the image on the homepage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. It may help you.

```
<?php 
   $productId = 10;
   $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
?>
```

Comment: You should not use the object manager except you really have a reason for it. Better use Dependency Injection, see Documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanx for precious reply.

Comment: How to get the product id dynamically without static values

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, it's better to use [Service Layer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/service_layer.html) in Magento 2.

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
    ...
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
/**
 * @var ProductFactory
 */
protected $_modelProductFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...      
    ProductFactory $modelProductFactory,  
    ...
)
{           
    $this->_modelProductFactory = $modelProductFactory; 
    ...
}

public function getProductInformation($productId)
{
    return $this->_modelProductFactory->create()->load($productId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to get just a couple of attributes about the product and want to avoid loading the product, you can do that using a collection. Just inject the class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`
like so:

```
public function __construct(
    Context = $context,
    //...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    //...
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collection = $collectionFactory();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);   
}
```

and then create a simple collection like this:

```
$productID = 10;
$product = $this->_collection
    ->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['some_attribute'])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productID)
    ->getFirstItem();
return $product->getSomeAttribute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$productId = 10;
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')- 
>load($productId);
?>
```