# How to get product information from product id in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want get price,special price from product id in magento 2 for all product types we use below code but not working

```
    <?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory as SubscriptionCollectionFactory;

class Observer extends AbstractModel{

      protected $_storeManager;
      protected $_productCollectionFactory;
      protected $_objectManager;
      protected $_currency;

      public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    SubscriptionCollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
     ) 
     {  
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;   
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->subscriptionCollectionFactory  = $subscriptionCollectionFactory;
    $this->_currency = $currency;
     }

     public function sendalert() { 

    $data = $this->subscriptionCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('subscription_status', 0);



    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prodIds = $collection->getAllIds();



    foreach($prodIds as $productId)
    {
        $om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $pdata = $this->_objectManager()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        echo '>>'.$pdata->getPrice();
    }

      }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load product by id magento2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894534/how-to-load-product-by-id-magento2)

Answer (score 3):

Other answers tell you to use the `ObjectManager` directly, but you shouldn't do this because you would work around of the [Dependency Injection](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) pattern. `ObejctManager` should only be used during bootstrapping, or if you really have a reason to use it.

The better way is to use the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById` method. You can inject your `ProductRepository` with automatic constructor injection like you did with your other constructor parameters:

```
$productRepository; 
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $pr
    // ...
    ) 
{  
    $this->productRepository = $pr;
    // ....
}
```

Then use

```
$productRepository->getById(1234);
```

If you need more information on how to use the repository, maybe [this tutorial](http://dusanlukic.com/magento-2-a-simple-product-feed) will help you.

Comment: but shos this error :- main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Area code is not set' in /var/www/html/magento25/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:139

Comment: If you are not running in developer mode clear generation folder and clear cache: `rm -rf var/generation/* var/cache/*`.

Comment: Can you explain what is merchant beta?

Comment: A public release of Magento 2 that was realesed before the stable version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?php  
   $productId = 8;
   $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
   echo $currentproduct->getName(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me

```html
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product      = $productObject->load('enter product id');
```

Here ObjectManager class is like service or factory class which is used to create an object of product model.

Let me know if you have any double

Comment: but shows this error in exception.log:-main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Area code is not set' in /var/www/html/magento23/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:139

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
/**
 * @var ProductFactory
 */
protected $_modelProductFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...      
    ProductFactory $modelProductFactory,  
    ...
)
{           
    $this->_modelProductFactory = $modelProductFactory; 
    ...
}

public function getProductInformation($productId)
{
    return $this->_modelProductFactory->create()->load($productId);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow . Please add more explanation to the answer. Every answer must have a sufficient explanation on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Using ObjectManager.

```
<?php $product_id = 45; // product id
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
?>
```

Using Factory Method.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

Use in phtml file.

```
<?php
    $product_id = 45; // product id
    $product=$this->getLoadProduct($product_id);
    echo $product->getName();
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In Magento 2 proposed to use service layer for this. Try use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById method to get product by id

Try below code

```
$prod_id = "Your product id goes here";
$om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$pdata = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prod_id);
```